# TFS Advanced Build Parameters does not show

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I need to add `Pre-build script path` parameter to my build definition file. I do not see where it is accepting the parameter nor does it show much under Advanced Builds as shown below:
[image]

When looking at the build process template file `GitTemplate.12.xaml`, it shows that it should accept more parameters as seen in `AdvancedBuildSettings`:

[image]

The value for the parameter is, as you can see, `PostActionScriptPath` parameter is there:

```
New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(" { ""MSBuildArguments"": """",
""MSBuildPlatform"": ""Auto"", ""PreActionScriptPath"": """",
""PreActionScriptArguments"": """", ""PostActionScriptPath"": """",
""PostActionScriptArguments"": """", ""RunCodeAnalysis"": ""AsConfigured"" } ")
```

Anyone knows how to turn this parameter on so I can enter a value for `PreActionScriptPath`? This also happens in another build definition that clearly shows that it accepts a parameter in the .xaml file.

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: This is from Team Foundation Service online. Also using Visual Studio 2013 Preview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When editing the build process template, go to the Arguments, look for `Metadata` and edit the value. Look for the parameters that are not showing, click them then on the right hand side for the label `View this parameter when:` and select `Always show the parameter`.